# Is calling a function faster than SendMessage()?

Tags: c, winapi

Is calling a function that does the same thing as the message you're sending faster than calling `SendMessage()`?

For example in the code below in `case WM_RBUTTONUP:`, which is faster, calling `EnableTwoWindows(firstWnd, secondWnd);`or sending `SendMessage(hwnd, CUSTOM_MESSAGE_ENABLE_TWO_WINDOWS, 0, 0);`? And what are the advantages and disadvantages of calling a function vs sending a message?

```
void EnableTwoWindows(HWND hwnd1, HWND hwnd2)
{
    EnableWindow(hwnd1, TRUE);
    EnableWindow(hwnd2, TRUE);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND firstWnd, secondWnd;

    switch(msg)
    {
    case CUSTOM_MESSAGE_ENABLE_TWO_WINDOWS:
        EnableWindow(firstWnd, TRUE);
        EnableWindow(secondWnd, TRUE);
        break;

    case WM_RBUTTONUP:
        //EnableTwoWindows(firstWnd, secondWnd); //Is calling this function faster? or
        //SendMessage(hwnd, CUSTOM_MESSAGE_ENABLE_TWO_WINDOWS, 0, 0); //Is sending message faster?
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Calling one function requires less code to execute than calling more than one function. I do not understand the question you are trying to ask.

Comment: @IInspectable I wanted to know which would execute faster

Comment: More code takes more time to execute. Your question is the moral equivalent of asking: *"Is 10 larger than 1?"* You know the answer already.

Comment: You just waited for the user to click a button. How long did that take. Get some perspective!

Comment: Of course if the target window is in a different thread the difference is even greater.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling the function directly is faster than going through a `SendMessage` call.

This can be easily inferred, when you look at what `SendMessage` does: It first needs to determine, whether the target window is owned by the same thread, and if so, retrieve the window procedure, and finally call that.

If the target window is owned by another thread, it gets more costly, as the `SendMessage` call has to queue up the message on the target thread's queue, wait for it to invoke a message retrieval function, and can only return, when the target thread has dispatched the message and produced a return value. In that case, however, it is **mandatory** to call `SendMessage`. Manipulating windows from threads other than the owning thread results in undefined behavior. `SendMessage` ensures, that the manipulations run on the same thread, that owns the window.

In addition, the compiler can inline the direct function call. This is not possible when calling `SendMessage`, since the compiler cannot see its implementation.

Performance is not an issue: You are responding to user input. The user is the bottleneck. Correctness, on the other hand, is essential. If you need to decide, use the following rule: If the windows you are manipulating are owned by a thread other than the calling thread, use `SendMessage`. If the windows are owned by the calling thread, go for a direct function call.

Comment: Nice answer,  I would only stress out that precisely, the fact that the message may be pumped to the window procedure, can be a strong advantage over the direct API function call - this is relevant if we are trying to update the UI from a secondary thread, for example.  Calling the function directly in a secondary thread may lock or crash the application, while SendMessage() is a perfectly safe way to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

> It costs more to call multiple functions than it does to call one function.

Comment: Meh - you got +3.  When I supply 'succinct' answers, I get downvoted:(

Comment: Well, but then this answer strikes a masterful balance between pointing out the obvious and doing it with that fancy unexpected Markdown feature that I had no idea was enabled here on SO...

Comment: @MartinJames: I made it into a CW (Community Wiki) answer — precisely because I don't want the credit for pointing out the obvious.

Comment: @stakx: The fancy Markdown was mainly a way to get to 15 characters in the answer without saying anything (much) more.